# How to use R function in Sparklyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I am researching how to use R function on line but still have hard time figuring out. Please help.

My initial code looks like:

```r
whatever %>%
group_by(a) %>%
summarize(count=n()) %>%
collect() %>%
ggplot(aes(x=a, y=count)) +
geom_point()
```

I want to repeat this multiple times since there are other columns I want to check with the same function.

So I wrote:

```r
point_dist <- function(dta, vari) {
dta %>%
group_by(vari) %>%
summarize(count=n()) %>%
collect() %>%
ggplot(aes(x=vari, y=count)) +
gemo_point()
}

point_dist(whatever, a)
```

but keep telling me:

```r
Error in eval_bare(sym, env) : object 'a' not found
```

Don't know why.

I either don't know if this is the right direction I shall go.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is related to non-standard evaluation that `dplyr` functions tend to give you. When you reference `a` in your first call to `point_dist`, R attempts to evaluate it, which of course fails. (It's even more confusing when you have some variable named as such in your calling environment or higher ...)

NSE in `dplyr` means you can do something like `select(mtcars, cyl)`, whereas with most standard-evaluation functions, you'll need `myfunc(mtcars, "cyl")`, since there isn't a variable named `cyl` in the calling environment.

In your case, try:

```r
point_dist <- function(dta, vari) {
  vari <- enquo(vari)
  dta %>%
    group_by(!!vari) %>%
    summarize(count=n()) %>%
    collect() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=!!vari, y=count)) +
    gemo_point()
}
```

This method of dealing with unquoted column-names in your functions can be confusing if you're familiar with normal R function definitions and/or are not familiar with NSE. This can be a good template for you if that's as far as you're going to go with it, otherwise I *strongly* urge you to read a little more at the first reference below.

Some good references for NSE, specifically in/around tidyverse stuff:

- https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html
- http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Comment: I really really appreciate your patient explanation. I also read through the first reference, very helpful. There is only typo in your code, the ggplot(aes(!!vari...)). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo. Can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are summarising your data and piping to ggplot, then you don't need to use `collect()`.

```r
df <- data.frame(group=sample(letters[1:10],1000,T))

df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group,n)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

If you are going to apply this summary and plot method to multiple columns, I would suggest trying `gather()` and then plotting everything at once using `+ facet_wrap()` and bar plots.

```r
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(letters[1:10],10000,T),ncol = 10))

df %>% gather(k,v) %>% group_by(k,v) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(k,n,fill=v)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  facet_wrap(~v) + theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: Based on [Yi Du's other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5808216/yi-du) and the [tag:sparklyr] tag, the use of `collect()` might be because there is a connection to non-local data such as through `sparklyr`. I am not a guru on it (please correct me if I'm wrong), but I think it is recommended in this case, in order to "realize" the pipe into local data (since I thought `ggplot(...)` doesn't know how to deal with promised data).

Comment: I just tried without collect() and it works. Thanks. Will this actually expedite the computational time without collect()?